# Inequality and strict inequality with infimums and measure proofs

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the first presented proposition and subsequent proof in this blog: [Proof that a non-negative set function and infimum induce an outer measure](https://angyansheng.github.io/notes/measure-theory-vii). Given that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu_0(S_n^k) < \mu^*(A) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$, how do we justify the non-strict inequality $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu_0(S_n^k) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu^*(A_n) + \epsilon$? Is there anything other to this than if $a < b$, then necessarily $a \leq b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though they assume that $\mu^{*}(A_n) <\infty$ for each $n$ it is necessary that the final sums are finite. If $a_n=1$ for all $n$ and $b_n=2$ for all $n$ then $a_n <b_n$ but $\sum a_n =\sum b_n$.

Answer (score 1):

If $0\le a_n<b_n$, then $\sum_n a_n\le \sum_n b_n$.

Consider $a_n=\sum_k\mu_0(S^k_n)$ and $b_n=\mu^*(A_n)+\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$.